# In Chef, Best way to deploy a single website from a package

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe, knife, winrm

I have a package including multiple websites and window services that I deploy them automatically from Team City using knife winrm remotely.

But I want to find a best way to deploy a single website (recipe) periodically that rest of the recipe doesn't run in a role to save time.

Would you like to share your idea?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can run a single recipe directly(-ish) via the `--override-runlist` (`-o`) command line option. This is generally not recommended though, as Chef is designed to be a convergent system and that means it models the state of everything. A better approach would be have a node attribute (or similar) with the requested version of the package, and only install it when the local version doesn't match the requested version. This provides both idempotence and convergence if implemented correctly.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @coderanger. I heard chef-client -o doesn't keep node.save which might not keep the state. Another method I heard is to use data bag to use if statement to provide the value to turn on or off the deployment which I'm familiar with.

Comment: The lack of node.save is just one of the many footgun-level issues with override run lists. They can be very useful when you know all the tradeoffs, but probably steer clear for now. As for the more general question of building application deploy recipes, see https://github.com/poise/application_examples/ for my Rails, Django, and Express examples.